# Why does Jest needs Babel to test async code?

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

The Jest ["An Async Example" guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) starts with:

> First, enable Babel support in Jest...

But I miss to see why and where does Jest needs Babel for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Node.js has supported `async` functions by default since version 7.6.0, so (as you suspected) `Babel` is **not** needed for `Jest` to run tests using `async` functions.

I just confirmed this by installing **only** `Jest` v24.6.0 and ran this test with Node.js v10.15.1:

```js
test('hi', async () => {
  const val = await Promise.resolve('hello');
  expect(val).toBe('hello');
});
```

...and it passed just fine.

---

On the other hand, `Babel` **is** required to use ES6 module syntax.

Many of the examples in the ["An Async Example"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) doc use ES6 module syntax (`export default ...`, `import * as ...`, etc.) so `Babel` **is** required for any of those examples to work.